# Abrir um banner quando acessa o site

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estou precisando colocar uma imagem para abrir automaticamente quando acessa o site, mas estou meio perdido nisso.

Comment: Especifique melhor sua pergunta!
Como você quer abrir? em pop-up? no próprio html '<img src="..."/>'...
edite sua pergunta para podermos tentar ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode usar um modal para exibir uma imagem quando o site é carregado.

Existem várias bibliotecas que incluem modals, como o [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html), [Bulma](http://bulma.io/documentation/components/modal/), [SemanticUI](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html), etc...

Se tu não usa nenhuma delas também têm bibliotecas que funcionam sozinhos ou com [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). Uma rápida pesquisa e achei estas: [Vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/), [Tingle](https://robinparisi.github.io/tingle/) e [SimpleModal](http://simplemodal.plasm.it/).

Teoricamente seria só adicionar um *handler* ao evento `DOMContentLoaded` no javascript.

```
// Com jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Criar e ativar modal aqui
})

// Sem jQuery
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Criar e ativar modal aqui
});
```